# Boot from a new drive?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, pcie

I got a little SSD I'd like to use as a boot drive on my media desktop, and I was wondering if there's a way to just switch booting to that new drive, so my other drive is just my media and can be upgraded in the future without disrupting the system? Running Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks!

ETA: I'd like to boot from the PCIe port is that matters.

Comment: If the computer can boot from that drive then just install the OS in that drive.

Comment: What I'm asking is whether it can be done without having to reinstall.

Comment: You often can reinstall quicker than any of the methods to move / or /boot to another drive. Then you can also restore any settings from your backup as a test that backup is valid since you still have old install to find anything missing in your backups.

Comment: I don't really understand why I'm getting a response like that on a forum like this? I'd rather learn than just be told not to bother because I must not be capable. So if you know anyplace that has a walkthrough for that, that'd be nice.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Thanks oldfred, but I've had issues with backup before with restoring settings as I wanted them, so I'd rather learn to move it if I can, or just install from scratch and not bother.